# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'export' while executing chunk.export

Tags: python-3.x, audio, split, export

I have a audio file, where i'am trying split and export it. But i'm facing the below error. Please let me know how to go about it

```
 from os import path
 AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath('C:\\Users\\anagha\\Documents\\Python Scripts')),"Python Scripts\\audioa.aac")

 chunks = split_on_silence(AUDIO_FILE,min_silence_len=500,silence_thresh=-16)

 for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):

    out_file = "C:\\Users\\anagha\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\res.aac".format(i)
    print("exporting", out_file)
    chunk.export(out_file, format="aac")
```

or

```
  for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
  chunk.export("/path/to/ouput/dir/chunk{0}.wav".format(i), format="wav")
```

Error:

```
 chunk.export(out_file, format="aac")
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-90-474a71cb8d64>", line 1, in <module>
chunk.export(out_file, format="aac")

 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'export'
```

Comment: what is split_on_silence ? Can you post the code of that method. I think the method is returning a list of strings. Is it imported from some library?

Comment: Yes, I actually changed the format of reading a audio file. Its working fine now